# How I can return two columns into a function?

Tags: database, oracle, function

How I can return two columns into a function?

For example: `"EmployeeName | salary"` and the values are `"Jonas Daniel | $2500$`

Comment: HI and welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you asking for the SQL syntax/query on how to return a single value combining 2 columns ? Could you provide us with a table structure and/or a some code/query you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ref cursor is one option:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_empno in number)
  2  return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select ename, sal from emp
  7                where empno = par_empno;
  8    return rc;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(7839) from dual;

F_TEST(7839)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING            10000


SQL>
```

Or, you could try this approach:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_test_row is object
  2    (ename     varchar2(20),
  3     sal       number);
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_test_tab is table of t_test_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_empno in number)
  2    return t_test_tab
  3  is
  4    l_tab t_test_tab := t_test_tab();
  5  begin
  6    select t_test_row(ename, sal)
  7    bulk collect into l_tab
  8    from emp
  9    where empno = par_empno;
 10
 11    return l_tab;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test(7839) from dual;

F_TEST(7839)(ENAME, SAL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
T_TEST_TAB(T_TEST_ROW('KING', 10000))

SQL> -- Or, a nice presentation
SQL> select * from table(f_test(7839));

ENAME                       SAL
-------------------- ----------
KING                      10000

SQL>
```

Or, you could create a procedure:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_empno in number,
  2                                      par_ename out varchar2,
  3                                      par_sal   out number)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    select ename, sal
  7      into par_ename, par_sal
  8      from emp
  9      where empno = par_empno;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_ename varchar2(20);
  3    l_sal   number;
  4  begin
  5    p_test(7839, l_ename, l_sal);
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Name = ' || l_ename ||', salary = ' || l_sal);
  7  end;
  8  /
Name = KING, salary = 10000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But, if you meant to return two scalar values, you might be out of luck.